# Preflight request is ok, then, after auth, response does not contain allow cors header

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, cors, asp.net-web-api2, ntlm

Asp MVC 5 app deployed on IIS 8.5.
Need to enable ajax request from a number of clients.

Server-side I have In WebApiConfig.cs

```
config.EnableCors();
```

In controller:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:59901", headers: "*", methods: "*", SupportsCredentials = true)]
public class ItemController : Controller
```

Client side

```
$("#getItem").on("click", function (e) {
    var myurl = "http://servername/item/details/1"

    $.ajax({
        url: myurl,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#result').text(jqXHR.responseText || textStatus);
        },
        success: function (result) {
            $('#result').text(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Running client from VisualStudio Origin is http://localhost:59901.

Running the ajax request I get the following in fiddler:

**1. Preflight request/response**

```
OPTIONS http://vrtsrv01.webdev.local/item/details/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: vrtsrv01.webdev.local
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://localhost:59901
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:59901/Home/Index
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,it;q=0.6,it-IT;q=0.4

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:59901
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, MaxDataServiceVersion
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sat, 13 May 2017 15:34:54 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

**2. GET request without credentials/ 401 error response**

```
GET http://vrtsrv01.webdev.local/item/details/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: vrtsrv01.webdev.local
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://localhost:59901
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Referer: http://localhost:59901/Home/Index
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,it;q=0.6,it-IT;q=0.4

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sat, 13 May 2017 15:34:54 GMT
Content-Length: 1352
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>401 - Autorizzazione negata: accesso negato a causa di credenziali non valide.</title>
....
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Errore del server</h1></div>
....
</body>
</html>
```

**3. GET request with NTLM token for auth / response without Allow CORS header**

```
GET http://vrtsrv01.webdev.local/item/details/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: vrtsrv01.webdev.local
Connection: keep-alive
Authorization: Negotiate <...NTLM TOKEN HERE ...>
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://localhost:59901
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Referer: http://localhost:59901/Home/Index
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,it;q=0.6,it-IT;q=0.4


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Persistent-Auth: true
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sat, 13 May 2017 15:34:58 GMT
Content-Length: 8557

{"id":1, .....}
```

**QUESTION**

Why after enabling MVC app for CORS and seeing the right response to preflight request, the response obtained after NTLM authentication does not contain the expected Access-Control-Allow-Origin header?

Comment: The edit you made is effectively an answer to the question, so you might consider adding it as an actual answer—and accepting it yourself—so that others who come across this question can more easily see what the solution is (and can even upvote it…)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED (...for now...)
The invoked action was a controller action returning Json. This does not work with CORS. I need to create an API controller, cannot use the existing controller. This leads to code duplication, but I have no time now to refactor the whole application to use a single controller both for MVC and API

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that it will help you, but it might help someone else looking to have both `NTLM` and `CORS` enabled.

**CORS enabling**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*") { SupportsCredentials = true };
        //SupportsCredentials = true means that we will add Access-Control-Allow-Credentials to the response.
        config.EnableCors(corsAttr);
    }
}
```

`SupportsCredentials = true` means that we will add `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` to the response.

**Other solutions,**

**global.asax.cs** - properly reply with headers that allow caller from another domain to receive data

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Context.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", Context.Request.Headers["Origin"]);
        Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,MaxDataServiceVersion");
        Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        Context.Response.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: In WebApiCOnfig I simply EnableCors(), then I use DataAnnotation in Controller class  [EnableCors()] with attributes, including SupportCredentials=true. And all is ok with response to preflight request, the right headers are returned. Then I do authentication and after successful authentication response does not have all the needed headers. I also tried an approach like the second one you suggest, but instead of adding headers in global.asax.cs I added them in Web.Config; in this case Headers are added twice, and nothing works as needed.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: @kranz Yes you can do it also. more help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn532203.aspx

Comment: @kranz one thing cros header not perfectly work for me when I add I web.config. So if you need add it global.asax.cs.

Comment: I cannot use Owin/Oauth, this is an intranet application and NTLM auth is the only way to go.